# Algebra question involving cubic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me solve this?

Approximate the solutions to two decimal places:

$$x^3-8x-3=0$$

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $x^3-8x-3 = 0$?

Comment: f(x)=((x^(3)-8x-3))

Comment: yes that is what I mean good sir.

Comment: This seems like a question in numerical analysis. Do you want to know possible methods or [just the answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3+-+8x+-+3+%3D+0)?

Comment: For approximate solutions to 0s of polynomials I would suggest type the expression x^3 -8x -3 = 0 into [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x3+-8x+-3+%3D0) to get an answer. If you're looking for methods of solution then let me know.

Comment: The answer would be nice indeed.

Comment: Both Tunococ and I have given links to the correct answer.

Comment: Is there an algebraic way of solving this.

Comment: @LittleJon Actually yes.

Comment: @LittleJon Yes, when faced with factoring a polynomial it's often useful to start with the rational root test. In this case it's particularly easy to apply since your polynomial is monic and $3$ is prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are feeling ambitious and curious you can also find the solutions using Cardano's method to come up with the roots of $x^3-8x-3=0$ with the result as follows

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{-19i\sqrt{15}}{18}+\frac{3}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{19i\sqrt{15}}{18}+\frac{3}{2}}$$

Then take the cube roots of the above to obtain the following result

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{15}}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{15}}{6}\right) = 3$$

$$\left(\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{9i\sqrt{3}-i\sqrt{15}}{12}\right)+\left(\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{-9i\sqrt{3}+i\sqrt{15}}{12}\right)=\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$

$$\left(\frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{9i\sqrt{3}+i\sqrt{15}}{12}\right)+\left(\frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{-9i\sqrt{3}-i\sqrt{15}}{12}\right)=\frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^3-8x-3=0$$
$$x^3-3x^2+3x^2-9x+x-3=0$$
$$x^2(x-3)+3x(x-3)+1(x-3)=0$$
$$(x^2+3x+1)(x-3)=0$$
$$x-3=0,x_1=3$$
$$x^2+3x+1=0,x_2=\frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{2},x_3=\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: The fact that $3$ is a root could have been detected with the rational roots test.

Comment: Then I divide by $x-3$ and got quadratic

Answer (score 2):

There is a closed form solution for cubics, but that is not what the question asks.  However, in this case, you'll find that there is a root at $x=3$.  Using synthetic division, we find that the quotient of the cubic divided by $x-3$ is $x^2 + 3 x+1$, which has roots at $x=\frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.  You may verify this by a quick inspection of the graph of the cubic:

[image: Cubic]